# EF4 two models one database, possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, mvp

I have been searching for this answer and can't seem to find anything, but with EF4 I want to create a base model and put in our 'foundation' and any new project we create if we need to add custom tables to that sites db is it possible to add a model with just those specific tables and link it to the model in our 'foundation' 
I can't seem to find a good resource on something like this and this seems to be like it would be a normal thing to have a reusable base model and a separate one for any one off's

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - in a way.

You would end up having two separate, distinct Object contexts - one from your "foundation" with the basic tables and classes, and another from project-specific model.

Trouble is: you cannot move entities from one context to another... so as long as those entities never have to interact in any way, then you'll be fine.

Comment: That Makes sense, thats a bummer though because they would have to interact with the base model... :( Thank you for your help!!!